# relating class number and narrow class number of a real field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am interested in finding out when the narrow class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1})$ is the same as the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1})$ where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity and $p$ a prime.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: keywords: signature cyclotomic units

Comment: Franz is of course correct, and for info, for $p<163$ the class number is $1$ (well-known) and the narrow class number is also $1$ except for $p=29$ and $p=113$ for which it is equal to $8$. For $p=163$ they are both equal to $4$.

Comment: Thank you both. @HenriCohen do you have a precise reference for this (the narrow class number)?

Comment: Among the references given in the preface of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-01512-1, there is Verhoek's thesis https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/verhoek.pdf